# Large array of pointers deletion

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

I have large array of pointer like:

```
int *m_Data[1000];
```

During the destruction, should I go element wise always or is there any better way?

```
for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
  delete m_Data[i];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int *m_Data[1000];
```

is an array of `1000` pointers to `int`s with automatic storage duration.

You need to call `delete` for every `new` and `delete[]` for every `new[]`, i.e. this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
    delete m_Data[i];
```

is correct only if you were previously doing something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
    m_Data[i] = new int;
```

---

*"is there any better way?"* - **Yes:**

```
std::vector<int> m_data(1000);
```

in this case the memory where elements reside will be automatically freed when the object is destructed (if needed, appropriate destructor will be called for each element).

Comment: I am dynamically allocating in the constructor with new for each element.

Comment: If I use vector as you said, should I do a deletion in the destructor as well? or will it be automatically deleted?

Comment: @AvbAvb `vector` handles the memory management of the array for you if you store objects.  If you store pointers, you either need to use a smart pointer class, or handle the memory deallocation yourself.

Comment: @AvbAvb note that what you have and a `vector` are semantically different. A vector is closer to a single, dynamically allocated array. So you have one contiguous block of memory that holds all your objects (`ints` in this case). An array of pointers is a different thing altogether. It isn't clear from your question whether this distinction matters.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a smart pointer (such as `std::unique_ptr`) instead of raw pointers, and not worry about manual deletion:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> m_Data[1000];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like:

```
int* m_Data = new int[1000];

// ...

delete [] m_Data;
```

Or:

```
int m_Data[1000]; // Why to allocate each element dynamically ?
```

In this case, you don't need to delete any element.

But if you need to allocate each element dynamically one-by-one:

```
int *m_Data[1000];
for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
    m_Data[i] = new int;

// ...

for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
    delete m_Data[i];  // To need to deallocate each element.
```

---

Why don't you use a container like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ?

```
std::vector<int> m_Data(1000);
```